# Convert date period to display a date format

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a SQL query which displays `yyyymm` in the following:

```
select  ([dimdate_fact_transac_TrnServiceDtId].[date_period]) as [date_period]
from [db].[dbo].[table]
```

Displays:

```
date_period
201304
201305
201306
```

How can I modify so the `date_period` comes out as `MMM-YY` like this:

```
date_period
APR-13
MAY-13
JUN-13
```

I am trying to do that for my SSRS report, but when I change the number format it doesn't show the date, which makes me believe it is sending it as a string rather than a date format.

Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should do:

```
 FORMAT(Fields!Date.Value, "MMM-yy")
```

source: [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/784d51be-3fa2-4b2f-89aa-ccf223ed8b8e/format-date-time?forum=sqlreportingservices).

Comment: It is coming from the SQL as String. When I do the above it shows `MMM-YY` in the report preview.

Comment: [This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/141fb460-8092-4ad7-b059-38a760c1e39e/how-to-convert-ddmmyyyy-format-string-to-date-type-in-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices) should help.

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit:

Added a much cleaner version (1a) in **SQL 2012**

**Method 1a**

For `SQL 2012` You can use the `Format` and `DateFromParts` method

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEFROMPARTS(date_period/100, date_period % 100, 1), 'MMM-yy')
```

**Method 1b**

Handle it in `SQL 2008/2005`

```
SELECT 
LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, 
                 CAST(date_period AS VARCHAR(6)) + '01'
            ), 
     3) 
+ 
'-' 
+ 
RIGHT(datePART(YY, CAST(date_period AS VARCHAR(6)) + '01'
              ), 
      2) 

as myDatePeriod
```

**Method 2**

Handle it in SSRS

```
=LEFT(MonthName
          (RIGHT(Fields!D.Value,2))
      ,3) 
& "-"
& Mid(Fields!D.Value,3,2)
```

**Note:** Added extra CRLF/spaces to make code readable